# Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception with message

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven

Please help me with the error.

I try to make a project using spring Boot and Maven. I connected the Spring Security, following the tutorial I have, but I met a error Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain'.

here is my POM file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.fuji.inventory</groupId>
    <artifactId>fujiInv</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>fujiInv</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Here is my Security Config :

```java
package com.fuji.inventory.fujiInv.configurations;

import com.fuji.inventory.fujiInv.service.CustomUserDetailsService;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/registration")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(8);
    }
}
```

here is my userController:

```java
package com.fuji.inventory.fujiInv.controllers;

import com.fuji.inventory.fujiInv.models.User;
import com.fuji.inventory.fujiInv.service.UserService;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserController {

    private final UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login(){
        return "login";
    }
    @GetMapping("/registration")
    public String registration(){
        return "registration";
    }
    @PostMapping("/registration")
    public String createUser(User user, Model model){
        if(!userService.createUser(user)){
            model.addAttribute("errorMessage",
                    "User with User Name" +user.getUsername()+ "already exists");
            return "registration";
        }
       return "redirect:/login";
    }
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String securityUrl(){
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

here is my User Model file:

```java
package com.fuji.inventory.fujiInv.models;

import com.fuji.inventory.fujiInv.models.enums.Role;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;


@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Data
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "username", unique = true)
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "email", unique = true)
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "phoneNumber")
    private String phoneNumber;
    @Column(name = "isActive")
    private boolean isActive;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "image_id")
    private Image avatar;
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Role.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
    @Column(name = "creationDate")
    private LocalDateTime creationDate;

    @PrePersist
    private void init() {
        creationDate = LocalDateTime.now();
    }

    //Security

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return roles;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return isActive;
    }
}
```

and User Service:

```java
package com.fuji.inventory.fujiInv.service;

import com.fuji.inventory.fujiInv.models.User;
import com.fuji.inventory.fujiInv.models.enums.Role;
import com.fuji.inventory.fujiInv.repositories.UserRepository;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    public boolean createUser(User user){
        String userName= user.getUsername();
        if(userRepository.findByUsername(userName) != null) return false;
        user.setActive(true);
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        user.getRoles().add(Role.ROLE_USER);
        log.info("Saved new user named {}!", userName);
        return true;
    }
}
```

I tried to add the dependencies, according the same issues of other people, I watched the videos from youtube....but any way I receive the error :

```java
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception with message: class org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter cannot be cast to class javax.servlet.Filter (org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter and javax.servlet.Filter are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:657) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:491) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1161) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:313) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:917) ~[spring-context-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at com.fuji.inventory.fujiInv.FujiInvApplication.main(FujiInvApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception with message: class org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter cannot be cast to class javax.servlet.Filter (org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter and javax.servlet.Filter are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter cannot be cast to class javax.servlet.Filter (org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter and javax.servlet.Filter are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.FilterComparator.compare(FilterComparator.java:57) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:355) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:220) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1307) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1721) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:179) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity.performBuild(HttpSecurity.java:1108) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity.performBuild(HttpSecurity.java:119) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:334) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.performBuild(WebSecurity.java:294) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.performBuild(WebSecurity.java:79) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:334) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:104) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0.CGLIB$springSecurityFilterChain$0(<generated>) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$2.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:258) ~[spring-core-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0.springSecurityFilterChain(<generated>) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    ... 22 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I can not start the project and continue to develop it because of this error.
I just started to learn spring boot and for that moment I dont know where I have to move...

Please, help.
Thank you in advance!

I tried to add the dependencies, according the same issues of other people, I watched the videos from youtube.
I hould start the project with Spring security connected.

Comment: You are using old spring security component, remove version from spring managed dependencies. Also use jakarta.servlet-api instead of javax because you are using spring boot 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because of

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Simply remove it.

You already have this and it is enough:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thanks! I solved it by using a new version of newest version of security. WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter  - is already removed because of deprecated in Spring boot 3.x.x. Any way, thanks for help!